# Is there any way to use OpenID on a Windows Mobile WinForm app?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, dotnetopenauth

I'm trying to use OpenID on my Windows Form application. Is there any way to use it? A web service or something simillar?

The application runs on a Windows Mobile 5.0 and above, with C# and Compact Framework 2.0 SP2.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenID does not apply to desktop or mobile apps -- only web apps.  For authenticating users to web services that a winforms app (mobile or otherwise) needs to access on behalf of the user, read up on [OAuth](http://oauth.net), which is targeted at just this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i looking for some implementation or how to implement OpenID on Windows Mobile application.

Comment: I know.  And what I'm telling you is no answer is applicable.  You won't find OpenID for a Windows Mobile app any more than you'd find OpenID on a desktop app.  There's no such thing.  Or if there was one (http://code.google.com/p/extremeswankopenid/ claims to have found a way), you've really got to question the security that it actually delivers, since a locally performed OpenID is completely open to subversion and identity spoofing.